# Julia: calculate an inner product using boolean algebra

Tags: julia, boolean-operations

I've got two boolean vectors `a = [1,1,1]` and `b = [0,1,1]` where obviously `1` stands for `true` and `0` for `false`.

I want to calculate their inner product using Boolean algebra. The result I want is therefore

```
1*0 + 1*1 + 1*1 = 0 + 1 + 1 = 0
```

because addition plays the role of exclusive or (XOR).

I know that the product part can be done like this

```
a = [true, true, true] # could also use ones(Bool, 3)
b = [false, true, true]

bitwise_prod = a .& b
```

but I don't know how to do the sum. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've actually found a good way now. First of all I don't need to use Boolean variables

```
a = [1, 1, 1]  # or ones(Int, 3)
b = [0, 1, 1]
```

I can then use `reduce` with the `xor` function.

```
reduce(xor, a .& b)
```

Note that I tried using the bitwise xor operator `$` that is found [in the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/mathematical-operations/#bitwise-operators) (inside an anonymous function) but this operator is deprecated and Julia 0.6.2 suggests the `xor` function instead. I do think having the function name makes it very neat.

Comment: `⊻`, which you get by typing `\xor`, should work, too.

Comment: You will need to use dot-broadcasted `a .& b` in 0.7 or later. You can also avoid allocating an intermediate array by `mapreduce(x->x[1]&x[2], xor, zip(a,b))`

Comment: The `mapreduce` version is a lot less readable though, compared to `reduce(xor, a .& b)`. Unless your arrays are really big, the `reduce` version is probably preferrable.